# Heroku build failed - Push rejected, failed to compile node.js app, failed to minify the bundle, many errors

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku

I was able to successfully deploy my MERN stack app about 12 hours ago. Since then I have not made any effective changes and deploying again to Heroku fails over and over again. Only my localhost, the app runs perfectly and the previous successful Heroku build is currently live and functional. However, I am not able to push new updates to the live app because of this.

Build logs:

```
Creating an optimized production build...
       Failed to compile.

       Failed to minify the bundle. Error: static/js/main.e01c6616.chunk.js from Terser
       TypeError: Cannot read property 'minify' of undefined
           at compiler.run (/tmp/build_0b7573e23cc40b96799733b6dbbf2347/client/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/build.js:164:23)
           at finalCallback (/tmp/build_0b7573e23cc40b96799733b6dbbf2347/client/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:210:39)
           at hooks.done.callAsync.err (/tmp/build_0b7573e23cc40b96799733b6dbbf2347/client/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:226:13)
           at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/tmp/build_0b7573e23cc40b96799733b6dbbf2347/client/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:32:10), <anonymous>:6:1)
           at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (/tmp/build_0b7573e23cc40b96799733b6dbbf2347/client/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:154:20)
           at onCompiled (/tmp/build_0b7573e23cc40b96799733b6dbbf2347/client/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:224:21)
           at hooks.afterCompile.callAsync.err (/tmp/build_0b7573e23cc40b96799733b6dbbf2347/client/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:553:14)
           at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/tmp/build_0b7573e23cc40b96799733b6dbbf2347/client/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:32:10), <anonymous>:6:1)
           at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (/tmp/build_0b7573e23cc40b96799733b6dbbf2347/client/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:154:20)
           at compilation.seal.err (/tmp/build_0b7573e23cc40b96799733b6dbbf2347/client/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:550:30)
           at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/tmp/build_0b7573e23cc40b96799733b6dbbf2347/client/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:32:10), <anonymous>:6:1)
           at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (/tmp/build_0b7573e23cc40b96799733b6dbbf2347/client/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:154:20)
           at hooks.optimizeAssets.callAsync.err (/tmp/build_0b7573e23cc40b96799733b6dbbf2347/client/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:1295:35)
           at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/tmp/build_0b7573e23cc40b96799733b6dbbf2347/client/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:32:10), <anonymous>:6:1)
           at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (/tmp/build_0b7573e23cc40b96799733b6dbbf2347/client/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:154:20)
           at hooks.optimizeChunkAssets.callAsync.err (/tmp/build_0b7573e23cc40b96799733b6dbbf2347/client/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:1286:32)
       Read more here: http://bit ly CRA-build-minify

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! client@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the client@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.PRRnP/_logs/2019-02-03T01_50_06_433Z-debug.log
error Command failed with exit code 1.
       info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
-----> Build failed

       We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys

       If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
       https://help.heroku.com/

       Love,
       Heroku

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
 !     Push failed
```

I have tried rolling back to a previous version and I still get this error. I tried deploying a completely different app to its existing live Heroku instance and that ALSO failed. Something happened over the last 12 hours.

I saw this link: https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/troubleshooting#npm-run-build-fails-to-minify but my react-scripts version is 2.0.6.

Not sure what it means by Failed to minify the bundle. And I'm not sure why I am unable to deploy completely different apps. Can anyone help me troubleshoot this?

Comment: Looks like this may be a heroku issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54499380/mern-stack-push-to-heroku-remote-rejected-master-master-pre-receive-hoo

Answer (score 0):

Terser is the reason. Try to updathe it and then try again, it should work.

```
npm install terser@3.14.1 --save-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exact problem. I removed my package-lock from .git-ignore and it worked. Hope it helps.